# How do I to copy files to flash drive in a recovery mode?

Tags: usb-drive, data-recovery, recovery-mode

It seems like to deleted too much files by `rm -r` and now I have the error of "the system is running a low-graphic mode" in Ubuntu and I have to work in Windows because of that.

However I can load it in recovery mode. I need to copy the files from `Downloads` folder to a flash drive. `Downloads` folder has them as I can see by ls command.

When I plug in a flash drive, there will be some messages saying that everything is ok (as I understood) and it's plugged. But when I go to `/media/my_name` and do `ls` then I don't see anything. I don't see anything in `/run/media/my_name` either(I'm not sure if should though).

I can't connect to the Internet for some reason. Ubuntu was installed by wubi.exe file.

How do I save the content of my `Downloads` folder to a flash drive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `fdisk -l` to see if you USB-Drive is identified. Remember the device (/dev/sdX)
Mount the USB-Drive manually with `mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt`
Copy thr whole Downloads-Folder with `cp -R /home/<your_user>/Downloads /mnt/`

Comment: it said that there was en error and had to specify file system. So I decided just to copy to sda (there were sda[1-4]-sdc). I did it, it copied for sure. But in Windows I can't find that folder.

Comment: when I did `mount /dev/sda /mnt` it said that it was already mounted or it was busy.

Comment: you need to mount the partition not the whole drive; /dev/sda1 not /dev/sda. But sda would not be your usb-drive. if you have one hdd this will be sda and your usb-drive is probably sdb. dont try to copy to sda - this is your root-partiton and you have to copy from sda to your usb-drive

Comment: I know but I decided to copy to disk C exactly which is in Windows. I have 2 visible logical disks in Windows: C and D.

Comment: Think of sda as the name of the device. sda1 would be a partition on that device. You want to copy your downloads to sda1 or sda2.